# I'm having trouble modifying a google game

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I would like to preface this post by saying I'm still new to html/css/js and so this may be an easy fix I just didn't see.

Recently I have been trying to modify the google game [blob beats](https://artsandculture.google.com/experiment/blob-beats/ZgF_e3-CO-iRPw?hl=en) to add custom songs. I found that the game is hosted in an IFrame which leads to [this site](https://cilex-axl-sandbox.appspot.com/cilex-blobhero/). The issue is that when you visit that site it displays the text "This experiment is not available on this platform.". This seems to be caused by 2 snippets of code within 2 JavaScript scripts called "axl.js" and "index.83adc410.js". The pieces of code that cause this are shown below:

axl.js problem code:

```
afterBodyParsed = () => {
    // Hack to detect non-iframe mode and block content.
    if (window.self === window.top && !navigator.userAgent.includes("SMLG")) {
      document.body.textContent =
          'This experiment is not available on this platform.';
      window.close();
      // Throw to interrupt the app ASAP.
      throw ('Experiment unavailable on this platform.');
    }
  };
}

let observer;
const check = () => {
  if (document.body) {
    afterBodyParsed();
    observer && observer.disconnect();
  }
};
observer = new MutationObserver(check);
observer.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true});
check();
```

index.83adc410.js problem code:

```
t = ()=>{
   if (window.self === window.top && !navigator.userAgent.includes("SMLG"))
      throw document.body.textContent = "This experiment is not available on this platform.",
      window.close(),
      "Experiment unavailable on this platform.";
}
```

An important note would be that if I try to modify the index.83adc410.js code it brings me to the axl.js script; I don't know why it does this or what this means.

Solutions I have tried:

I tried adding a breakpoint into axl.js and then changing the if statement to always evaluate to false. This caused the error to not appear for a little however upon stepping the breakpoint or closing the dev tools page it showed the error.

I tried importing the script that sets up the game and calling that after the error has already shown. I haven't been able to import it properly as dev tools console says I have the wrong path even though I am 80% sure I have the correct path.